# How does copyright work for puzzles and ciphers?

Tags: cipher, puzzle-creation

How does copyright (and/or patents) work for puzzles? Can puzzle formats (like type of code/cipher, scheme, or method of posing a question) be copyrighted, or does only the specific puzzle get protected?

For instance, if I was the first person to ever create a crossword puzzle, do I have copyright protection of the crossword puzzle, or only the specific puzzle I made?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Copyright only protects specific expressions and not ideas, so it would only protects a specific instance of a puzzle and not the type. However, you can patent a puzzle type ([according to this law.se answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/47865)), or trademark the name.

Comment: Note that unlike copyright, patents in the US last for a maximum of 20 years.  So even if the crossword puzzle *were* patented, the idea is very much in the public domain by now.